# Why genitive pronoun "des" used with proper nouns?

Tags: personal-pronoun

Is there a particular reason that one sometimes finds, for instance,

> *Mit dem Werke **des** Angelus Silesius*
>
> *Die Leiden **des** jungen Werther*
>
> *Die Karriere **des** Jürgen Klinsmann*

instead of using "*von*" to denote possession?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a question of [Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29). "Des" + proper name is much more formal than "von" + proper name.

I can think of three ways to express the genitive of a proper name:

- "die Karriere von Jürgen Klinsmann": colloquial, appropriate for spoken language
- "die Karriere des Jürgen Klinsmann": very formal, even for written language
- "Jürgen Klinsmanns Karriere": appropriate for both spoken and written language. I'd say you can't make a mistake if you go with this one.

With "Die Leiden des jungen Werther" the last option won't work because of the adjective (quite apart from the fact that it is a book title, and you can't just rephrase it). The first option "die Leiden vom jungen Werther" sounds entirely awkward, again, because of the adjective, because it needs a definite article along with the preposition. Thus, the option with "des" is the only one that really works here.

Comment: Good explanation! I disagree that "Die Leiden vom jungen Werther" sounds awkward because of the adjective, though - it's the combination of the very modern, highly colloquial von + dative construction and the very old-fashioned word "Leiden" that makes it sound weird. Something like "Was suchst du?" "Die Akte vom letzten Patienten." would sound completely natural, despite the adjective.

Comment: True. I was stuck in the mindset of literature and Goethe, and "Die Leidem vom jungen Werther" really didn't fit. That made it sound awkward to me at the moment, but now I've taken a step back, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

*Des* + genitive is the traditionally correct way to do it, although the colloquial von + dative has almost entirely taken over, a trend parodied in the book "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod" ("The dative is the genitive's death").

Answer (score 0):

Das 'des' ist nicht veraltet, steif oder förmlich, sondern schlicht richtig, während 'von' schlicht falsch ist.

Der Grund dafür ist, dass 'des' einen simplen Sachverhalt präzise ausdrückt, während 'von' oft mehrdeutig ist. Man erkauft sich also hier die Freiheit, ohne etwas dafür zu bekommen, denn es gibt kein positives Argument 'von' zu verwenden.

'Ich habe den Ball von Klinsmann' kann nämlich richtig sein, auch wenn es nicht Klinsmanns Ball ist. Ich kann Klinsmanns Ball von Völler haben, und Völlers Ball von Klinsmann.

Ich finde es lachhaft, die schlechte Sprache mit der Verbreitung des Fehlers zu legitimieren, wo es gute Gründe gäbe, sich dem entgegenzustellen.

Da Amtspersonen auch nur mit Wasser kochen und auch nicht mehr Disziplin walten lassen als andere, kann von einem mehr förmlichen Charakter des 'des' nicht gesprochen werden. Im Gegenteil klingt das 'des' völlig rund und richtig und wird überhaupt nicht als besonders wahrgenommen, wenn man es benutzt, es sei denn, der Zuhörer achtet besonders darauf.

Beweis: Wie viele 'des' und Genitive enthielt der Text?

Comment: Die Frage bezog sich auf "des" mit Eigennamen. Könntest Du bitte auf diesen Aspekt noch eingehen?