# Welche Präposition für "admirer of"?

Tags: word-choice

Wenn man sagt, "I am an admirer of Mr. X, sagt man ich bin ein Bewunderer [des/von/auf/etwas ander] Herr X?"

Tatsachlich ist Herr X, Frederick the Great, King of Prussia. Ist "King of Prussia" "König [von des auf etwas ander] Preußen"," oder "Preußens König" oder etwas ander?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/why-genitive-pronoun-des-used-with-proper-nouns and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebrauchlich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrichs des Großen, König Preußens.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrichs des Großen, Preußens König.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrichs des Großen, des Königs Preußens.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrichs des Großen, König von Preußen.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrichs des Großen, des Preußenkönigs.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer von Friedrich dem Großen, ...

Bin ich nicht. :)

- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Frank Zappas.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer des Frank Zappa.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer von Frank Zappa.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer Herrn Zappas.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer des Herrn Zappa.
- Ich bin ein Bewunderer von Herrn Zappa.

Answer (score 3):

Also das ist nun etwas komplizierter.

Man kann sowohl sagen

> Ich bin ein Bewunderer des Königs von Preußen

*Erklärung:
Da "des" einen Genitiv erzwingt, muss sobald als Objekt der Bewunderung ein genitivisches Konstrukt verwendet wird, "des" benutzt werden, bzw. anders herum.*

als auch, obwohl seltener

> Ich bin ein Bewunderer von Preußens König

*Erklärung: Da Preußens König in diesem Fall als Dativisches Objekt steht, muss "von" verwendet werden.*

---

Im Bezug auf den Kommentar von user2553:

Sobald außer dem Titel "König von Preußen" auch der Name - hier Friedrich der Große - verwendet wird, ist die dativische Verwendung häufiger anzutreffen, da Namen und Genitive im aktuellen Sprachgebrauch selten in Kombination zu finden sind:

> Ich bin ein Bewunderer von Friedrich dem Großen, dem König von Preußen im Jahr X

dann auch häufig anzutreffen ist:

> Ich bin ein Bewunderer Friedrich des Großen, des Königs von Preußen im Jahr X

Hierbei wird die Präposition ausgelassen und im Genitiv impliziert.

"auf" findet als Objektbezug im Deutschen keine Verwendung sondern fast ausschließlich als Positionspronomen ("auf dem Tisch" u. ä.)

Comment: Ich würde die von-Konstruktion nun nicht als seltener ansehen als die Genitivkonstruktion. Gibt es dazu Daten? Sobald ein „Name bewundert“ wird, würde ich sogar sagen, dass die von-Konstruktion häufiger ist als die Genitivkonstruktion.