# Form of genitive for proper nouns

Tags: genitive, proper-noun

This [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/why-genitive-pronoun-des-used-with-proper-nouns) gives some examples of genitive with proper nouns.

> Mit dem Werke des Angelus Silesius
>
> Die Leiden des jungen Werther
>
> Die Karriere des Jürgen Klinsmann

Is it always the case that proper nouns are unchanged in their genitive forms? In particular, can we say the following?

> Die Akten des amerikanischen State Department
>
> Die Mitarbeiter des New York Department of Education

Comment: related : http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7693/genitiv-von-fallnamen

Comment: Wouldn't "Die Leiden des jungen Werthers" be right? I heard that "Die Leiden des jungen Werther" is grammatically wrong, but grammar wasn't considered important in the time of "Sturm und Drang".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This forum has [a good discussion](https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,45761,45774,quote=1) on the topic.

Linked from there are some canoo.net pages.

[For people](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/FKlassen/Name-Person1.html):

```
Personennamen haben im Genitiv Singular ein s, wenn sie ohne Artikel stehen:
Goethes Dramen
das Reich Kleopatras
Joachims Spielzeug
Elisabeths Thronbesteigung

Personennamen sind im heutigen Deutschen in der Regel endungslos, wenn sie mit Artikel stehen:
die Dramen des jungen Goethe
das Reich der schönen Kleopatra
das Spielzeug des kleinen Joachim
das Leben der heiligen Elisabeth

Vereinzelt kommt bei männlichen Personennamen, die mit Artikel stehen, auch die Genitivendung -s vor (selten, veraltet oder gehoben):
Nachgestellt:   
„Die Leiden des jungen Werthers“    (Titel eines Werks von Goethe)
das Spielzeug des kleinen Joachims      (selten, nicht von allen als korrekt akzeptiert)
Vorangestellt:  
des [kleinen] Joachims Kreisel  (gehoben, vgl. Stellung Genitivattribut)
Weiblich auch vorangestellt immer ohne -s:
der [heiligen] Elisabeth Leben  (gehoben, vgl. Stellung Genitivattribut)
```

For geographic names canoo has again a useful link, [geographic names with article](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/FKlassen/Name-Geo-23.html):

```
Weglassen der Genitivendung s:
Die Genitivendung s kann bei vielen (vgl. Wörterverzeichnis) mit Artikel verwendeten geographischen Namen auch weggelassen werden. Zum Beispiel:
des Libanons oder des Libanon
des Balkans oder des Balkan
des Engadins oder des Engadin
des Atlantiks oder des Atlantik
des Kongos oder des Kongo
Ebenso:
des Elsasses oder des Elsass
```

So it seems there's no definitive, set in stone rule.

I didn't find anything about foreign names.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Roberts answer, the suffix -s is only omitted on names if the name is after an article ("des", "eines"). If the order is changed so that the article gets left out, then also names have to have the suffix -s. (If the name is ending on an s or a similar sound like -sch, instead of the -s an apostrophe is added)

Examples:

> das Werk des Angelus Silesius <-> Angelus Silesius' Werk
>
> Die Leiden des Werther <-> Werthers Leiden
>
> Die Karriere des Jürgen Klinsmann <-> Jürgen Klinsmanns Karriere

If you are using expressions from other languages that have a special meaning to themselves, you can treat the original expression like a name.

Examples:

> Die Akten des American State Department <-> Die Akten des amerikanischen Außenministeriums
>
> Die Mitarbeiter des New York Department of Eduction <-> Die Mitarbeiter des New Yorker Ministeriums für Bildung

Answer (score 2):

Your first examples are all names, and they remain unchanged.

With other nouns, you need to use the Genitive case; for example "Jäger des verlorenen Schatzes", "Herr des Hauses", "Regisseur des Films", or "bester Schauspieler des Theaters".

Other terms like "Meister der Musik" or "Chef der Behörde" or "Verwalter der Finanzen" remain without Genitive-S cause you would not add one anyway; the Genitive of "Behörde" is also "Behörde", and so on.

In your examples with the English terms, you can decide to not translate them and hence also not add the Genitive-S. They are correct as you used them.

Comment: Kann man bei `Die Fischwelt des Mains ist reicher als die des Rheins` die S auch weglassen? Muss man? (Die Aussage selbst erhebt nicht den Anspruch korrekt zu sein).

Comment: Man kann das S nicht weglassen, es gehört zum Genitiv.